# Performing an outer join on two Ruby Arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, join, outer-join

Let's say I have two Arrays in Ruby, containing user IDs.

These are the old users:

```
== old ==
1
2
3
4
```

And these are the new:

```
== new ==
2
3
4
5
6
```

I want to **find out the IDs of new users**, so in that case, 5 and 6. I guess what I want is a left outer join of NEW and OLD, but I don't know how to do that with simple arrays.

I'm relatively new to Ruby, so there might be a simple and effective solution for this, rather than iterating over everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
old = [1, 2, 3, 4]
new = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
p new - old #=[5, 6]
```

Comment: Haha, that's just too simple. Thanks a lot, I really feel stupid now!

Comment: You could perform this task in any language with relative ease, but Ruby makes it *very* easy. =)