# How would I return elements in array1 that are not in array2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects, type Lab, `existing_labs`, and a different array of Labs, `new_labs`. I have defined my own `==` comparator for Lab.

`existing_labs` is Labs that already exist in the db.
`new_labs` is Labs to be saved, based on their existence in the db already.

Right now I am doing this

```
new_labs.each do |l|
  lab = Lab.new(l)
  exists = existing_labs.map{ |existing_lab| lab == existing_lab }
  lab.save unless exists.include? true
end
```

This works, but can be slow if either or both of the arrays is large. I'm sure there has to be a better way to do this!

Edit for clarity:

My question is: Is there a good way to return all of the Lab that are present in `new_labs` that are not present in `existing_labs`, using my `==` method?

Comment: here you have the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592918/performing-an-outer-join-on-two-ruby-arrays

Comment: Close, but I need the comparison between the elements in the two arrays to use the `==` method I wrote (it is in the Lab model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_labs.each do |l|
  lab = Lab.new(l)
  lab.save unless existing_labs.any?{|existing_lab| lab == existing_lab }
end
```

Should be somewhat faster, because no array of trues and falses is created for each lab. Also, `any?` quits when one `true` is found.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not at all  clear, but here is a refactorization of your code:

```
(new_labs.map{|l| Lab.new(l)} - existing_labs).each(&:save)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a [set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) out of them and apply the `difference` method.

Comment: This seems to work like `ary1 - ary2`, where it is returning a set that is equal to the set on the left of the operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `-` method:

```
> ary1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ary2 = [2,3]
> ary1 - ary2
=> [1, 4, 5]
```

Another one:

```
ary1.select { |e| not ary2.include? e }
```

Any of these methods imply iteration on the background, but I think the `-` method wins on performance, maybe a couple of benchmarks would be good.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to use my `==` method, thus `ary1 - ary2` is always returning an array equal to `ary1`, while `ary2 - ary1` is always returning an array equal to `ary2`.

The onliner you included seems to always return the like elements in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

**returns the elments in array1 that are not in array2**

```
> ary1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ary2 = [2,7,9,3]
> ary1 - ary2
=> [1, 4, 5]
```

**returns the elments in array2 that are not in array1**

```
> ary1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ary2 = [2,7,9,3]
> ary2 - ary1
=> [7,9]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to use my `==` method, thus `ary1 - ary2` is always returning an array equal to `ary1`, while `ary2 - ary1` is always returning an array equal to `ary2`.